# Javascript - error extending object

Tags: javascript

My code is like following:

```
function Example(){}
Example.myMethod = function(){};
function SpecificExample(){}
SpecificExample.prototype = Object.create(Example.prototype);
SpecificExample.prototype.constructor = SpecificExample;
```

I want `SpecificExample` extends `Example`. Why this code doesn't work?

Comment: `Example.myMethod = function(){};` is a function attached to your constructor, not a prototype method, use `Example.prototype.myMethod = function(){};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example.myMethod is a function attached to the constructor function/object, but it is not part of its prototype. This could be called a static function (and in ES6 it is exactly that). To make them part of your prototype, add them to the prototype itself:

```
function Example(){}
Example.prototype.myMethod = function(){};
function SpecificExample(){}
SpecificExample.prototype = Object.create(Example.prototype);
// As @JaredSmith said, you shouldn't change the constructor, and why would you?
// function SpecificExample(){} IS your constructor. So...
// SpecificExample.prototype.constructor = SpecificExample;
// should simply be removed.
```

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah technically a lot of stuff is possible, but yeah, you're right, better be correct. Let me change that.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, I know it is like a static method (I need it), the problem was that I can't change the constructor. @JaredSmith there are something like performance problems?

Comment: More like unexpected behavior problems. Put a line `Object.prototype = null;` at the top of your script file as an example of why not to mess with built in stuff...

Comment: @Joy Actually, quick question: are you trying to make a sort of inheritable static method? Because I don't get why you want to change the constructor (certainly not since you are changing it to the same function that _already is_ your constructor)...

Comment: Also *why* you'd want an inheritable static method, which would almost certainly be an xy problem...http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah, I know, that defeats the point of a static method altogether, but okay, I was just guessing as to what they want to accomplish...